# Pagination with Twig and Eloquent-5.2

Tags: php, pagination, eloquent, twig, slim

After following this video tutorial on building a [PHP Authentication System](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGKUvioJly40RJZchSG2-34) with Slim/Twig and Eloquent 5.2.

I have finished the video tutorial and have a working system.
But I am failing to add pagination to the all user list on the [25th episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOJetM8zGzI&index=25&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGKUvioJly40RJZchSG2-34) of the tutorial.

**Everything seems to work fine. but when I press page 2,3,4,etc... I am still getting the page 1 data.**

Here is the code I have so far:

***routes/user/all.php***

```
    $app->get('/users', $authenticated(), function() use ($app) {
        $users = $app->user->where('active', true)->paginate(5);
        $users->setPath($app->urlFor('user.all'));

        $app->render('user/all.php', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    })->name('user.all');
```

***view/user/all.php***

```
{% extends 'templates/default.php' %}

{% block title %}All Users{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h4>All Users</h4>
    {% if users is empty %}
        <p>No registered users</p>
    {% else %}
        {% for user in users %}
            <div class="user">
                <a href="{{ urlFor('user.profile', {username: user.username}) }}"><img src="{{ user.getAvatarUrl({size: 18}) }}"> {{ user.username }}{% if user.getFullName %} | {{ user.getFullName }}{% endif %}</a>
                {% if user.isAdmin() %}
                    [Admin]
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {{ users.render()|raw }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "A146\\": "app/A146"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*",
        "twig/twig": "~1.21",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
        "hassankhan/config": "0.8.*",
        "illuminate/database": "5.*",
        "illuminate/pagination": "5.*",
        "alexgarrett/violin": "2.*",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "~1.1",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "*"
    }
}
```

**Here is the output I get:**

```
<div class="row">
<h4>All Users</h4>
    <div class="user">
        <a href="/pcb/public/u/Admin"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/...?s=18&amp;d=identicon"> Admin</a> [Admin]
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        <a href="/pcb/public/u/Jamarcus22"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/...?s=18&amp;d=identicon"> Jamarcus22 | Abbie O&#039;Hara</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        <a href="/pcb/public/u/jWalker"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/...?s=18&amp;d=identicon"> jWalker | Salvador Douglas</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        <a href="/pcb/public/u/Karelle00"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/...?s=18&amp;d=identicon"> Karelle00 | Harmon Ryan</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        <a href="/pcb/public/u/lCarter"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/...?s=18&amp;d=identicon"> lCarter | Lilly Stokes</a>
    </div>
<ul class="pagination"><li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li> <li class="active"><span>1</span></li><li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=2">2</a></li><li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=3">3</a></li><li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=4">4</a></li><li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=5">5</a></li><li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=6">6</a></li><li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=7">7</a></li> <li><a href="/pcb/public/users?page=2" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's been a month and a few days. I also encountered your problem, I just got my solution for it.

What I did was, I called the `Paginator` class then used a static method to force the pagination to whatever page I am in.

```
Paginator::currentPageResolver(function() use ($current_page) {
    return $current_page;
});
```

Then call the data that you wanted to be paginated. Here's my whole code below.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

$app->get('/controller/clients', $controllerAuthenticated(), function() use ($app) {

    $request = $app->request;
    $current_page = $request->get('page');

    Paginator::currentPageResolver(function() use ($current_page) {
        return $current_page;
    });

    $clients = $app->client->where(function($query) use ($client_name, $country_id) {
        if ($client_name != '') {
            $query->where('client_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $client_name .'%');
        }

        if ($country_id != '') {
            $query->where('country_id', $country_id);
        }
    })
    ->orderBy('client_name', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(1);

    $clients->setPath($app->urlFor('controller.client.all'));

    $app->render('/controller/client/all.twig', [
        'clients'   => $clients,
        'countries' => $countries,
        'request'   => $request
    ]);
})->name('controller.client.all');
```

I forgot where I saw the answer though, I'll post a link to a reference once I found it.

Comment: its been a while since i revisited this project. but your solution works 100% flawlessly!